# Not able to access style property of QT Quick QML Slider component

Tags: qt, qml, slider, qtquick2, qt-quick

I am trying to customize `Slider` QML Component but getting error for `style` property.
I want to make the slider `handle` smaller and also change some colors and so on, so I am trying to modify the style.
I found different behavior with multiple versions of the `QtQuick.Controls`.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Rectangle {
    property int slideFrom: 0
    property int slideTo: 10
    property int slideStep: 1
    property int slideValue: 0

    Slider {
        width: 100
        height: 50

        snapMode: Slider.SnapAlways
        from: parent.slideFrom
        to: parent.slideTo
        stepSize: parent.slideStep
        value: parent.slideValue

        style: SliderStyle {

        }

    }
}
```

If I `import QtQuick.Controls 2.14`
I get Error for style property as "Invalid property name style".

If I `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4`
I get error for `snapMode`, `from` and `to` as "Invalid property name".

I want both the properties and I see issue with imports.
I have no idea if we don't have `to`, `from` and `stepSize` in older version how we can manage the slide or is there some different way of using it?

Comment: As you want the `snapMode` .. you need to import `QtQuick.Controls 2.14` ..  then style the controls2  control

Comment: Thanks, how do I change the size of the handle is there any direct properties available to change the handle size? I am not able to find any.

Comment: should be simple once you familiarize .. like this `handle: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 34
                implicitHeight: 34
                radius: 12
            }`